# Snowflake filtering for next fiscal quarter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got this date column (closing_date) with fields that look like this e.g. 2023-01-20
How do I dynamically filter for only records where the date is in the **next fiscal quarter**?

| Closing_date | Name | Order_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-20 | Joe | 123 |
| 2023-01-20 | Joe | 456 |

Only the second record in the table should pull in because this fiscal quarter and year ends at the end of January.
Can I do this w/o having to update my date filter each quarter?

Answer (score 0):

Some date math should do the trick:

```
WHERE YEAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE(), 3))*10 + QUARTER(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 3)) = YEAR(Closing_date)*10 + QUARTER(Closing_date)
```

Comment: I think it didnt quite work :/ E.g. 2022-12-15 was dropped but thats still FY Quarter 4

Answer (score 0):

So if we define a variable to state the first month of a finacal year, here in New Zealand it's 1st April:

[corrected: to do the `cur_date_projected` of current date]

```
set fin_month = 4; // April is the first day on NZ fin year

with data(Closing_date, Name, Order_id) as (
    select * from values 
    ('2024-01-20'::date,    'Joe',  123),
    ('2023-01-20'::date,    'Joe',  456)
)
select *
    ,dateadd(month,(-$fin_month)+1, Closing_date) as date_projected
    ,date_trunc('quarter', date_projected) as date_in_fin_years
    ,year(date_in_fin_years) || 'Q' || quarter(date_in_fin_years) as date_as_fin_str

    ,dateadd(month,-$fin_month+1, CURRENT_DATE) as cur_date_projected
    ,dateadd('quarter', 1, date_trunc('quarter', cur_date_projected)) as cur_date_in_fin_years
    ,year(cur_date_in_fin_years) || 'Q' || quarter(cur_date_in_fin_years) as cur_date_as_fin_str
from data
```

gives:

| CLOSING_DATE | NAME | ORDER_ID | DATE_PROJECTED | DATE_IN_FIN_YEARS | DATE_AS_FIN_STR | CUR_DATE_PROJECTED | CUR_DATE_IN_FIN_YEARS | CUR_DATE_AS_FIN_STR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-20 | Joe | 123 | 2023-10-20 | 2023-10-01 | 2023Q4 | 2022-07-10 | 2022-10-01 | 2022Q4 |
| 2023-01-20 | Joe | 456 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-10-01 | 2022Q4 | 2022-07-10 | 2022-10-01 | 2022Q4 |

so if we swap to `fin_month` to 1, and then put those `date_projected` and `cur_date_projected` into a WHERE clause

```
select *
from data
where date_trunc('quarter', dateadd(month,(-$fin_month)+1, Closing_date)) = dateadd('quarter', 1, date_trunc('quarter', dateadd(month,-$fin_month+1, CURRENT_DATE)))
```

gives:

| CLOSING_DATE | NAME | ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-20 | Joe | 456 |

Comment: Hey Simeon! Thank you so much for helping me answer this question and another question I had. I think I wasn't clear with my question but I'm looking to filter for results only that are closing in 1 financial quarters dynamically. You helped me translate the closing date into string but how can I go ahead and filter for date +1 no matter which quarter I'm currently in and w/o having to use where date > x

Comment: sorry I missed the typo in `CUR_DATE_PROJECTED` and had assumed seeing how to put these values into a WHERE clause would make intuit sense.